# Comparison, exclusion, and popping elements from a list (Python)

Tags: python, list, replace, indexoutofboundsexception

I want to compare a number (dist) against each element of a sorted list (my list).

If the number is smaller than the first element in myList, than I have to proceed and find the right place for dist, eliminate the first element in myList and shift the list.

My main problem now is tha case when dist is smaller that the 1st elemnt in myList. The index is out of range ...

```
dist = 10
mylist = [40, 30, 20, 15] # this is a sorted list

for j in range(0, len(mylist)):
    if mylist[j] < dist &  dist> mylist[j+1]:
        print (mylist[j], '<' ,dist, '>', mylist[j+1])
        #drop 40
        #shift the list so that is becomes: [30,20, 15,10]
```

Comment: Use `and` not `&`.

Comment: @ChristianDean Funnily enough it still works, because of bitwise precedence it becomes `mylist[j] < dist > mylist[j+1]` which is still the same. Talk about a stroke of luck...

Comment: `dist> mylist[j+1]` this is what causes you the problem because at the last iteration of the for loop, `j` will exceed the largest index in your list and you will get the error

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Huh...you're right. What coincidence.

Comment: @KGS `and` operator evaluates the first condition before proceeding to the rest of conditions (if any) , his approach is correct except using the right operand as @Dean mentioned.

Comment: @Yahya, while this condition might work with the current list in the OP, try it with something like `[40, 30, 20, 15, 5]` you will see that it is exactly what makes it crash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you want to insert `dist` at its right position and knock off the first element. This is fine, but you have a few issues. The major one being your condition, and I'm not talking about the `&`. You'll want to make sure `dist` is greater the current, but lesser than the next. You do that like this:

```
if mylist[j] < dist < mylist[j+1]:
```

You'll also have to run till one lesser than `len(mylist)` to avoid index out of bounds.

Another trick you can use is `for...else` which will work for the corner case where `dist` was not inserted anywhere else.

In short, try this:

```
for j in range(len(mylist) - 1):
    if mylist[j] < dist < mylist[j + 1]:
         mylist.insert(j, dist)
         mylist = mylist[1:]
         break
else:
    mylist.append(dist)
    mylist = mylist[1:]
```

Alternatively, you can run from 1 to `len(mylist)`, and compare check for `mylist[j - 1] < dist < mylist[j]`.

Comment: Thanks very much, for the explanations. It has helped me alot.